# Generics and the question mark

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to use a generic list, but the initialization method only returns a `List`.
The following code works well:

```
List tmpColumnList = aMethodToInitializeTheColumnList();
tmpColumnList.add("ANICELITTLECOLUMN");
```

Java accuses that I'm using a raw type and I should paramerize the list.
So I added the question mark parameterize this list.

```
List<?> tmpColumnList = aMethodToInitializeTheColumnList();
tmpColumnList.add("ANICELITTLECOLUMN");
```

Problem is: Now the `add(..)` method doesn't work anymore.
I cannot assure that the list only contains `String`s as `aMethodToInitializeTheColumnList()` is not implemented in *my* code.

What is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: How did it work in the first snippet? Missing `new`...

Comment: Abel: A function call initializes the List. I'll add it to clarify this thing.

Comment: Fix the initialisation method?

Comment: Tom: It's not in my code, see my edit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the Generics Tutorial. Thanks to [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839969/generics-and-the-question-mark/1839982#1839982)!

> It isn't safe to add arbitrary objects
>   to it however:
>
> ```
> Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
> c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
> ```
>
> Since we don't know what the element
>   type of c stands for, we cannot add
>   objects to it. The add() method takes
>   arguments of type E, the element type
>   of the collection. When the actual
>   type parameter is ?, it stands for
>   some unknown type. **Any parameter we
>   pass to add would have to be a subtype
>   of this unknown type.** Since we don't
>   know what type that is, we cannot pass
>   anything in. The sole exception is
>   null, which is a member of every type.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance (I'm not a Java guy). What is the purpose of having it if it does not work?

Comment: @noloader: the purpose is this: if you have a method parameter of type `Collection<?>`, you can pass in a `Collection<String>`, a `Collection<Integer>` or a `Collection<Whatever>`, and within the method you can get the contents of those collections as type `Object`. That you cannot add anything to the collection is important because it ensures that  the original type constraints are not violated.

Answer (score 18):

You probably want to use `List<String>` - that's how Generics are intended to be used, i.e. add information about what kind of objects will be in a collection. If you're actually going to have a List containing mixed types (which is usually a sign of bad design) use `List<Object>`

For more information about the use of wildcards, look at the [Generics Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). But they're really only relevant when defining your own generic classes, or methods with generic parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I cannot assure that this list only contains strings.

Comment: In that case you could use List<Object>, or maybe something else, dependent on what you know the list will contain (for example List<Serializable>)

Comment: In the Generics Tutorial there's the solution, see my own answer. I will consider accepting your answer because you gave me the hint.

Answer (score 16):

If you use `<?>`, you mean you aren't going to use the parametrized type anywhere. Either go to the specific type (in your case it seems `List<String>`) or to the very generic `List<Object>`

Comment: I don't want to specify it, but why is the normal `add` method failing then?

Comment: Well, the compiler enforces semantic consistency. You say you won't use the parametrized type, so it doesn't let you. The `add` method expects a parameter which type is the generic parameter, so you're not allowed to use it if you don't specify one.

Comment: Because the type is *unknown*. The compile has no possibility to determine whether a `String` would be appropriate so you’re not allowed to add a `String` to the list. (Actually, you’re not allowed to add anything to that list, except for `null`.)

Answer (score 8):

Another option in this case would be to declare your list to be a

```
List<? super String>
```

since this models *exactly* what you know about it.  You say that you don't know exactly what its type bounds are, but from your second line it's fair to assume that it must be able to contain strings.

This compiles and to my mind, is a little nicer than a `List<Object>` as it encodes your uncertainty as to what can actually go in the list.  Basically, you can only *add* Strings to it, but when you call `get()` the returned element could be anything (and Java will correctly infer this type to be `Object`).

In practical terms, the only difference between this and `List<Object>` is that the latter would allow `tmpColumnList.add(3)` or `tmpColumnList.add(new Thread())` etc.  I much prefer the semantics it carries as well as the practicality.

Answer (score 2):

The `List<?>` means that the list is (or could be) typed, but the type is unknown**. So adding something to it could be wrong**, if you happen to be outside of the type. Because it is unknown, you are warned.

You can use `List<Object>`, which means **a list that can contain any type**.

Comment: @furtelwart True, my wording was poorly chosen :-). But the point of this compile-time error is that the compiler signals that the code is potentially wrong. BTW, it is the whole point of the Generics subsystem as implemented, to search code safety at compile-time, and add casts at runtime...

Comment: Forgive my ignorance (I'm not a Java guy). What is the purpose of having it if it does not work?