# Java Collection<Object> or Collection<?>

Tags: java

I try use List instead of List

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
...
list.add(1); //compile error
```

What i do wrong and how cast new value to Integer? 
 Maybe i shoud use List in my project?

Comment: Is there a reason you cant declare list as List<Integer> ?

Comment: Try List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: @nidhin - bad idea to use raw types

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839969/generics-and-the-question-mark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List<?>` means *a list of some type, but we don't know which type*. You can only put objects of the right type into a list - but since you don't know the type, you in effect **can't put anything in such a list** (other than `null`).

There is no way around this, other than declaring your variable as `List<Integer>`.

Comment: So is there ever a time to use `Generic<?>`? Would it be for operations on the generic class that aren't relevant to the type of object it contains? (And why would such operations ever be useful in isolation?)

Comment: Yes. For example, `Class<?>` has quite a lot of methods which don't make any use of the type parameter. For `List<?>` (which is the same as `List<? extends Object>`, you can get the size, compare it to other lists (or non-lists), and get `Object`s out of it. Just nothing type-specific.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The generic type ***always*** has to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
...
list.add(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

? means some type, you have to specify the Type as Integer. so the correct syntax would be :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```