# asynctask and java generics

Tags: java, android, generics

I have this class

```
public final class AsyncTaskManager<T extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> & IProgressTrackerTask 
       & ICancelTask> 
....
T mAsyncTask;
....
public void setupTask(T asyncTask) {
    mAsyncTask = asyncTask;
    mAsyncTask.execute();
}
.....
```

But on the line

```
    mAsyncTask.execute();
```

Eclipse says:

```
Type safety: A generic array of capture#4-of ? is created for a varargs parameter
add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

I've added suppressWarning but I have ClassCastException during executing doInBackgound.
As said [here](http://beautifuldiscovery.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/strange-classcastexception-with-asynctask/) all types must be checked before executing AsyncTask.
How can I solve my problem - make my class generic and disable this warning?
Thanks a lot!

EDITED:
Just to clarify how is used. I have abstact AsyncTask:

```
public abstract class ManagedAsyncTask<T, E, G> extends AsyncTask<T, E, G> 
implements IProgressTrackerTask, ICancelTask {
```

and AsyncTask that's doing real work:

```
public class GetTask extends ManagedAsyncTask<Void, Void, SearchResult> {
```

and in activity:

```
mAsyncTaskManager = new AsyncTaskManager<GetTask>(this, this);
mAsyncTaskManager.setupTask(new GetTask());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too sure about the generic part of it, but I think you're getting that error because the `execute` method on an AsyncTask expects as an argument the parameters of the `doInBackground` method.  This will be an array of whatever type the first question mark of `AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>`.  If you're not expecting any data in your `doInBackground`, you can pass `(Void[])null` (essentially an array of nothing) in order to satisfy the compiler.

Here's the documentation for the `execute()` method of the AsyncTask.  If you're still having problems, other parts of this page can be very helpful for configuring and using your AsyncTask:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29

Edit: Just to clarify, the `Void` in `(Void[])null` should be of whatever type the parameter of `doInBackground` is.  I'm assuming, since you aren't passing anything into execute, that you're using Void as that parameter to indicate that there's no necessary data. You may have implemented it differently and need to cast null accordingly.

Comment: Thank yout for your answer, but see: I have abstract AsyncTask, and extended this AsyncTask my WorkingAsyncTask. All types here are checked. I put it into method setupTask and get this warning...

Comment: The accepted answer (and some others) here seem to be on to something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839969/generics-and-the-question-mark  Looks like you can't use a question mark to signify the AsyncTask parameters because then the compiler will expect whatever you pass as the argument to execute to extend ?, not a good situation.  I think your question marks have to be more concrete, either declaring what ? extends, making it an Object, or giving it another generic variable like T.  Take a look at the answers to that question and see if they help.

Comment: seems you are right! When I try public final class AsyncTaskManager<T extends AsyncTask<Void, ?, ?> & IProgressTrackerTask & ICancelTask>  - OK! But when public final class AsyncTaskManager<T extends AsyncTask<T2, ?, ?> & IProgressTrackerTask & ICancelTask, T2> - not checked :(
Is there any way to improve second variant?

Comment: I don't user generics that much so I'm not entirely sure.  What are you using as your argument for execute in that second case?  Have you tried `(T2[])null`?

Comment: I've just corrected string with public final... and get this warning again (in second case).