# The difference between instanceof List and instanceof List<?>

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-erasure, erasure

I know that we cannot invoke `instanceof List<E>` because `List<E>` is not a reifiable type. Both `instanceof List` and `instanceof List<?>` work; however the eclipse IDE suggests use `instanceof List<?>`.

I wonder why it suggests unbound wildcard `instanceof List<?>` instead of raw call `instanceof List`. Does the unbound wildcard `instanceof List<?>` have any advantage over the raw call `instanceof List`?

Thank in advance.

**Edit 1**: In effect, `instanceof List` and `instanceof List<?>` is same as the compiler will erasure the type when compiling. But beside the cosmetic reason as Mena points out, does it have any other reason to use `instanceof List<?>` in favor of `instanceof List`?

**Edit 2**: According [this entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/mcimadamore/entry/diagnosing_raw_types) from Oracle:

> 4. The type of an instanceof/cast expression is raw
>
> This happens very frequently, as javac forbids instanceof expressions
>   whose target type is a generic type; for casts, the compiler is
>   slightly more permissive since casts to generic type are allowed but a
>   warning is issued (see above). Anyway, the raw type should be replaced
>   by an unbounded wildcard, as they have similar properties w.r.t.
>   subtyping.
>
> `Object o = new ArrayList<String>();` 
>   `List<?> list_string = (List)o;`
>   `//same as (List<?>)o boolean b = o instanceof List; //same as o instanceof List<?>`

Thus, we can infer that beside the cosmetic reason as Mena said and restriction to use genenics, `instanceof List` and `instanceof List<?>` are the same.

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9165161/2764279) may help you

Comment: Duplicate of [Generics and the question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1840022/5020253)

Comment: There is a question if almost the same title as your question ... have you at least tried to search for it first?

Comment: Yes, I saw that question. It's answer explain that both have the same effects since the wildcard is erased at compile time. But why the eclipse recommend `instanceof List<?>` instead of `instanceof List<>`?

Comment: Because `instanceof List<>` wouldn't compile and `instanceof List` should be avoided, because raw-types should be avoided (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), so it tries to teach you to avoid them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"`List<E>` is not a reifiable type" is not the best way to formulate why `instanceof` won't compile.

The `instanceof` operator verifies the type of your object at runtime.

As such, [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) prevents Java from knowing its parametrized type (the type between the `<>`).

Hence a raw `List` (equivalent to a `List<Object>`) or a `List<?>` (i.e. a `List` of unknown type) practically mean the same here, although the raw syntax is usually advised against (here, for cosmetic reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because `List` is a Raw Type and `List<?>` is not. Raw types are potentially very dangerous because they can have many strange side effects.

I will post a reference as soon as I can find it.

Comment: There is no difference... The wildcards are neglected at compile time...

Comment: Oh really? And what's a big deal of non-raw type if you can pass anything? It it was `List<? extends Something>` then it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

List is itself a type. So there wont be any difference if you change the type inside of it.